# Intro.js: highlighted area doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, intro.js

I'm using the very interesting javascript library [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/).

However, in my application, the highligted area becomes almost completely white.

I'm guessing that this is some CSS conflict, but what can I do to determine the cause of this problem?[image]

Comment: have you tried to debug this? Using firebug in mozilla or chrome's built in inspect?

Comment: Yes, I tried both firebug and chrome dev tools. I tried to enable/disable some css lines on the "styles" panel, but I couldn'd see any visible effect on the page.

Comment: Seems to be a known bug with intro.js no solution for it yet https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/109

Answer (score 12):

Extracted from issue #109 (https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/109):

```
.introjs-helperLayer {
    background: transparent;
}

.introjs-overlay {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

.introjs-helperLayer:before {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000em rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    opacity: 1;
}

.introjs-helperLayer:after {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

This will solve your problem. Hope it helps as it did for me! Shout to @weili1977 and @exoJSON who provided the answer in GitHub.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this.

Comment: This helped a lot but my button that's underneath still cannot be clicked.  The overlay is blocking interaction.

Comment: After adding these styles it works as expected. I am wondering why it isn't fixed in the main branch :(

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be fixed by setting absolute position for parent element:

```
.introjs-fixParent {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is common for users using table row element. I solve mine by adding these lines to css.

```
.introjs-relativePosition > td { position: relative; }
.introjs-showElement > td { z-index: 9999999 !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a useable result with this:

```
.introjs-helperLayer {
     mix-blend-mode: overlay !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the target element position to absolute (in corresponding CSS) and it works now!
see here - http://prntscr.com/1dl0db

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any jsFiddle or any online example of your problem but I try to answer your question in this way:

1. It's seems you're using another UI library like ExtJs or something,
   make sure you don't have any CSS conflicts.
2. Try to change
   `data-intro` and `data-step` in another element, for example if now
   you have the `data-intro` and `data-step` in the `form` element,
   change it to an upper element or a `div`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ExtJs. This is definitely some conflict involving z-index. Unfortunately I was not able to investigate further, and it's easier to find an alternative. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @pvieira I'm trying to fix the problem in further versions.

Answer (score 0):

In the Introjs.css, setting the z-index to 1 for the introjs-helperlayer class fixes this issue. However, I do not know the full implication of this change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to highlight a Table Row ()? If so I experienced this problem too. Someone posted a fix in the github issues section: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/146